# display data from database in mvc razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I am trying to display data from database using mvc razor,  but I am unable to do so.
Here is my code

I am trying to display the total price, group by twine id. but nothing shows up.
what could be the possible reason?

**view**

```
@model CustomerRevenueModel

@using Nop.Web.Models.Customer

<div class="tab-body revenue">


    @foreach (var revenue in Model.DesignWiseSplits)
    {
        <ul class="info">
            <li> Twine:<span class="order-status ">@revenue.Twine</span></li>
            <li>Designer Share:<span class="order-date">@revenue.DesignerShare.ToString()</span></li>
            <li>Total:<span class="order-total">@revenue.Total</span></li>
        </ul>
    }
```

**Controller**

```
 model.CustomerRevenueModel = PrepareCustomerRevenueModel();

[NonAction]
    protected virtual CustomerRevenueModel PrepareCustomerRevenueModel() 
    {
        var model = new CustomerRevenueModel();
        model.DesignWiseSplits = _orderService.DesignWiseSplits(_workContext.CurrentCustomer.Id);
        return model;
    }
```

**Model**

```
namespace Nop.Web.Models.Customer
{
public partial class CustomerRevenueModel : BaseNopModel
{
    public IList<DesignWiseTotal> DesignWiseSplits { get; set; }
    public IList<Nop.Web.Models.Order.OrderDetailsModel.OrderItemModel> AllDesignerOrderItems { get; set; }
    public int TotalRevenue { get; set; }

}
}

namespace Nop.Services.Orders
{
public class DesignWiseTotal
{
    public decimal Total { get; set; }

    public decimal DesignerShare { get; set; }

    public Twine Twine { get; set; }
}
}
```

**Services**

```
public virtual IList<DesignWiseTotal> DesignWiseSplits(int customerId)
    {
        var query = _orderItemRepository.Table;

        return query.Where(oi => oi.Product.Designer_Id == customerId)
                        .GroupBy(oi => oi.Product.Twine)
                        .Select(oi => new DesignWiseTotal
                        {
                            Total = oi.Sum(x => x.PriceExclTax),
                            Twine = oi.Key
                        }).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: "but I am unable to do so." Can you be more specific? Do you get an error?

Comment: Nothing gets displayed on my view. I have no errors in the code. Database is fine. 
I just can't understand what possibly might be wrong

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not returning the model to the view from the controller action. Your action should look something like this. Make sure your view is named the same as your action or specify it in the View() method

```
public ActionResult PrepareCustomerRevenueModel()
{
    var model = new CustomerRevenueModel();
    model.DesignWiseSplits = _orderService.DesignWiseSplits(_workContext.CurrentCustomer.Id);

    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: it is returning in PrepareCustomeRrevenueModel function

Comment: Ok and if you're debugging is the next line after the controller returns the razor code in the appropriate view you want?

Comment: Are any of the revenue objects in the loop not null?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using  `<li> Twine:<span class="order-status ">@revenue.Twine</span></li>` Use  `<li> Twine:<span class="order-status ">revenue.Twine</span></li>`

Change @revenue to revenue